# GPS sensor plugin in Ignition

Tags: ignition-fortress

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi!

Is there an equivalent to the "libhector_gazebo_ros_gps.so"  plugin in Ignition (Fortress)? From what I can see, the NavSat-plugin is the closest, but I can't find any parameters to link it to a model.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28643/gps-sensor-plugin-in-ignition/) by [knuttu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/67665/knuttu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

By browsing github I found out how to use the NavSat plugin (ignition-gazebo-navsat-system if that was unclear).
So basically you have to do something like this if you are using SDF:

```
<model name="NavSat">
  <pose>0 0 0.05 0 0.0 0</pose>
  <link name="link">
    <inertial>
      <mass>0.1</mass>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>0.000166667</ixx>
        <iyy>0.000166667</iyy>
        <izz>0.000166667</izz>
      </inertia>
    </inertial>

    <collision name="collision">
      <geometry>
        <box>
          <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
        </box>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="visual">
      <geometry>
        <box>
          <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
        </box>
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <sensor name="navsat" type="navsat">
      <always_on>1</always_on>
      <update_rate>1</update_rate>
      <topic>navsat</topic>
    </sensor>
  </link>
</model>
```

For this to work you also need to set the spherical coordinates for navsat. I did this is in my world SDF file, and it looks like this:

```
<spherical_coordinates>
  <surface_model>EARTH_WGS84</surface_model>
  <world_frame_orientation>ENU</world_frame_orientation>
  <latitude_deg>-22.986687</latitude_deg>
  <longitude_deg>-43.202501</longitude_deg>
  <elevation>0</elevation>
  <heading_deg>0</heading_deg>
</spherical_coordinates>
```

However, I was not able this from an URDF file, which is what I want to do.

EDIT:
If you are using ROS2 you can call the service /world/world_name/set_spherical_coordinates service from your launch.py file to set the spherical coordinates.

---

Originally posted by [knuttu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/67665/knuttu/) with karma: 1 on 2022-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

> However, I was not able this from an URDF file, which is what I want to do.

Your URDF file should include the `<sensor>` tag within the `<gazebo>` tag. Without this structure, Gazebo might not recognize and properly initialize the sensor. Make sure your URDF structure looks something like this:

```
<gazebo>
  <sensor name="navsat" type="navsat">
    <always_on>1</always_on>
    <update_rate>1</update_rate>
    <topic>navsat</topic>
  </sensor>
</gazebo>
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to include `<spherical_coordinates>` in the `.urdf` file. As far as I know, it should be placed in the world's `.sdf` file.